# How do I solve the Riccati Differential Equation with fsolve in MATLAB / Octave?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matlab, nonlinear-system, optimal-control

Let's say that I have this equation. This is the Riccati Differential Equation:

$$P A + A^T P - P B R^{-1} B^T P + Q  = 0$$

I know $ A, B, Q, R$. My goal is to find $P$. How do I use the MATLAB / Octave command fsolve to find $P$ ?

**EDIT:**
$$ $$

Here is the answer - An example to get LQR matrix.

```
>> fun = @(P, A, B, Q, R) P*A+A'*P-P*B*inv(R)*B'*P + Q
fun =

@(P, A, B, Q, R) P * A + A' * P - P * B * inv (R) * B' * P + Q
>> p0 = 0.1*ones(2)
p0 =

   0.10000   0.10000
   0.10000   0.10000

>> P = fsolve(@(P) fun(P, Amat, Bmat, Q, R), p0)
P =

   55.67637    0.57241
    0.57241    2.29935

>>

>> inv(R)*Bmat'*P
ans =

   2.2269e-02   2.2895e-04
  -1.4350e-03  -5.7645e-03

>> lqr(Amat, Bmat, Q, R)
ans =

   2.2269e-02   2.2899e-04
  -1.4353e-03  -5.7644e-03

>>
```

Comment: fminsearch could also be possible to use. I have more experience using it anyway. A third approach could be to do a linearization and minimize a regularized least squares norm of vectorization of P using Kronecker products for matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't think that fminsearch is the right solution. I'm using GNU Octave and Octave have fsolve as a built in function. The same as MATLAB has.

Comment: What do you mean by "right" solution? Is it part of a course where you have to use a particular function to pass? If so then you are supposed to show any own attempts at the problem in the question.

Comment: So if I use the fminsearch, I can solve the Riccati equation?

Comment: Yes it should work. For example if you aim to minimize $\|PA+A^TP -PBR^{-1}B^TP+Q\|_2$. But whichever function you use you will need to get comfortable using the programming language so you know what you are doing.

Comment: You can use fsolve. You pass $P$ as a vector $p$ where all of the elements of $P$ are listed in $p$ in some order (e.g. row by row, or column by column). In your call function, you then reformat $p$ into $P$ and calculate the error, for example a 2-norm as @mathreadler describes above, and return the value.

Comment: Please! Can you show me? You might have the chance to get the green check on this question. :)

Comment: Oh don't worry. I've been hunting my share of credits and grades / "green marks" in my days. ;) Also you will need to learn use the help and documentation functions of the softwares you aspire to learn if you are to become efficient and skilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function, demofun:

```
function err = demofun(p, A, B, Q, R)
P = reshape(p, [3 3]); %% Reshape p to your desired matrix size
F = P*A+A'*P-P*B*inv(R)*B'*P + Q;

% Calculate the error value
err = sum(F(:).*F(:));

return
```

Then write the script that optimizes the function

```
A = randn(3);
B = randn(3);
Q = randn(3);
R = randn(3);

p0 = ones(9, 1)*0.1; % Initial guess for P, vectorized to p

tmp = fsolve(@(p) demofun(P, A, B, Q, R), p0);

P = reshape(tmp, [3 3]); % Reshape vectorized answer to matrix format
```

Comment: No need to use reshape. Let's say that I got those https://pastebin.com/b9q9rcv1 This will give me 
L = [2.2269e-02   2.2899e-04;  -1.4353e-03  -5.7644e-03] if I use the LQR command in MATLAB.